# Filling a matrix with a list of lists

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a list of lists with different lengthes:

```
{{a1,a2},{b1,b2},{c1,c2,c3},...}
```

Now I want to create a matrix the following way:

```
{{       0,        0, f[b1,a1], f[b2,a1], f[c1,a1], f[c2,a1], f[c3,a1],...},
 {       0,        0, f[b1,a2], f[b2,a2], f[c1,a2], f[c2,a2], f[c3,a2],...},
 {f[a1,b1], f[a2,b1], 0       , 0       , f[c1,b1], f[c2,b1], f[c3,b1],...},
 {f[a1,b2], f[a2,b2], 0       , 0       , f[c1,b2], f[c2,b2], f[c3,b2],...},
 {f[a1,c1], f[a2,c1], f[b1,c1], f[b2,c1], 0       , 0       , 0       ,...},
 {f[a1,c2], f[a2,c2], f[b1,c2], f[b2,c2], 0       , 0       , 0       ,...},
 {f[a1,c3], f[a2,c3], f[b1,c3], f[b2,c3], 0       , 0       , 0       ,...},
 {                                   ...                                  }}
```

If it weren't for those zero-blocks I could simplify use `flatten` on my nested list, but I somehow need to "remember" the structure it. Note that `a1,..` are just placeholders to better show what I mean. In reality `a1` could be equal to `b2` for example. Maybe one could do this in two steps and set the zeros in the second one. But I'm not sure how to do this without for-loops either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
blocks[l_List, f_] := Module[{m},
  m = Transpose@Outer[f, #, #] &@Flatten[l];
  (m[[#, #]] = 0) & /@ 
   Span @@@ (# + {1, 0} & /@ Partition[{0}~Join~Accumulate[Length /@ l], 2, 1]);
  m
  ]
```

---

```
blocks[{{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}, {c1, c2, c3}}, f] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

---

```
blocks[{{a1, a2, a3}, {b1}, {c1, c2}}, f] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
blocks[l_List, f_] := Map[f @@ # &,
Module[{m = 0, F = Flatten[l], Q},
ReplacePart[Table[Q[i, j], {j, F}, {i, F}],
Flatten[Tuples[#, 2] & /@ Map[++m &, l, {2}], 1] -> 0]], {2}]
```